# Mac OSX 10.7 Lion Audio Unit Effect template Failing to compile

Tags: c++, macos, audiounit, osx-lion

I just upgraded to Mac OSX 10.7 Lion. First of all, I hate the new spaces, I dislike not being able to access any directories deeper than my user directory, but lets get to the question.

I develop Audio Unit Plugins. I have a few whose code is compiling and working perfectly (they're even released for sale) in XCode 4.0.

But after upgrading to Lion and XCode 4.1, there are now two major compiling failures in the main audio unit .cpp file (mine is named TestAU.cpp) where the Process method resides. Below is the code that fails.

```
#include "TestAU.h" 

COMPONENT_ENTRY(TestAU) // FAIL c++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.

TestAU::TestAU(AudioUnit component) : AUEffectBase(component) // FAIL Expected ';' after top level declarator.
{
    CreateElements();
    Globals()->UseIndexedParameters(kNumberOfParameters);
    SetParameter(kParam_One, kDefaultValue_ParamOne );

    #if AU_DEBUG_DISPATCHER
        mDebugDispatcher = new AUDebugDispatcher (this);
    #endif

}
```

I'm having trouble solving this failure. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search in the Xcode documentation for [Technical Note TN2276](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2276/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011031) for instructions on updating an existing audio unit for Lion.

You have to replace

```
COMPONENT_ENTRY(TestAU)
```

with

```
AUDIOCOMPONENT_ENTRY(TestAU, Filter)
```

But there is a little more so read the document.

**Edit:**
BTW regarding your comment about not being able to access all directories you can find many locations in the Go menu of finder.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could you please link to the Technical Note TN2276. I'm having trouble finding it. I searched google and the developer library.

Comment: Never mind found it. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2276/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011031